# Swift Convert Optional String to Int or Int32 (Unwrapping optionals question)

Tags: swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I am trying to read a string and convert it to an int. I have a solution but it seems way too complicated. I guess I am still trying to wrap my head around unwrapping.

I have posted code below along with the compiler errors that I get with each solution.

In this example I try to read a string from UserDefaults and convert to an integer value.

```
static func GetSelectedSessionNum() -> Int32 {
    var sessionNum : Int32 = 0
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    let optionalString: String? = defaults.string(forKey: "selectedSessionNum")
    // this works but it's too complicated
    if let string = optionalString, let myInt = Int32(string) {
        return myInt
    }
    return 0

    // Error : optional String? must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'
    let t : String = defaults.string(forKey: "selectedSessionNum")

    if let s : String = defaults.string(forKey: "selectedSessionNum") {
        // error - Int32? must be unwrapped to a value of Int32
        return Int32(s)
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: There's nothing complicated about your working solution. It is the correct way. You have two optionals to deal with. BTW - why store the session number as a string instead of storing it as an actual number? That would make things much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast to `non optional Int32` in order to match your return type.

You can use any optional binding approach, or change your return type to `Int32?`

Answer (score 0):

If you want an *uncomplicated* solution save `selectedSessionNum` as `Int`

```
static func getSelectedSessionNum() -> Int32 {    
    return Int32(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "selectedSessionNum"))
}
```

otherwise double optional binding

```
if let string = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "selectedSessionNum"), let myInt = Int32(string) {
    return myInt
}
```

or the nil coalescing operator

```
if let string = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "selectedSessionNum") {
    return Int32(string) ?? 0
}
```

is the proper way

Comment: OP probably doesn't have a good reason to use Int32. from the title **String to Int or Int32 (Unwrapping optionals question)**

Comment: `integer(forKey:)` would even convert a string preference to an integer, if possible.

Comment: @MartinR Didn't know that. And what does it return if not possible? `0`?

Comment: The documentation says that *A string that represents an integer becomes the equivalent integer (for example “123“ becomes 123).* – If the string does not represent an integer then 0 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid optional bindings, you can use `flatMap`, when called on `Optional`'s it allows you to convert one optional to another:

```
return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "selectedSessionNum").flatMap(Int32.init) ?? 0
```

You'd also need the `??` (nil coalescing operator) to cover the scenarios where either the initializer fails, or the value is not present in user defaults.